# Is it possible to create a nullable foreign key constraint in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a nullable int8 column 'z_id' on a table 'XY'. The 'z_id' is the primary key of the 'Z' table. I'd like to have a constraint that maps the 'Z' entity to the 'XY' table if the 'z_id' is provided during persistense.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: the constraint should allow null values

Comment: Have you tried anything? Are you getting an error? Or is this just a problem you've made up in your head?

Comment: if the entity is persisted with a null in the 'z_id' field, an error is thrown that the contraint doesn't allow it.

Comment: What do you mean by "entity", what do you mean by "persisted", what is "the constraint" you're talking about, what is the actual error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you try to:

```
t=# create table z(i int primary key);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into z values (1);
INSERT 0 1
t=# create table xy(i int);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into xy values(1),(null);
INSERT 0 2
t=# alter table xy add constraint fk foreign key (i) references z(i);
ALTER TABLE
t=# select * from xy;
 i
---
 1

(2 rows)
```

And you probably had [same doubdts](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/o4527vgc2tl60snr5hbuv75hdob58n99n4%404ax.com)?..

Comment: It was a hibernate annotation mapping problem and not a postgres one. But thanks anyway